# How can I replace strings between <!-- comment --> with something else

Tags: javascript, regex, gulp

I am using gulp to facilitate my frontend deployment. I would like to replace some strings in index.html
For example, turning the following code like

```
<!-- js starts -->
<script src="xxxxxx/xxxx/xxx1.js"></script>
<script src="xxxxxx/xxxx/xxx2.js"></script>
<script src="xxxxxx/xxxx/xxx3.js"></script>
<script src="xxxxxx/xxxx/xxx4.js"></script>
<!-- js ends -->
```

into

```
<!-- js starts -->
<script src="xxxxxx/xxxx/all-one.js"></script>
<!-- js ends -->
```

I have installed gulp-string-replace, and it works fine with some simple regular expression. But my case seems contains some special characters, such as < ! -- >

This is my gulp code but not implemented what I want.
gulp.src('index.html').pipe( replaceString("(?<='')(.*)(?='')", "what I want") ).pipe( gulp.dest(target) );

Comment: Gulp is really poor. Go through Webpack tutorial.

Comment: It is not the time to replace this tool......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you always keep the text in the start and end comments the same, this works:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replaceString = require('gulp-string-replace');

let replacement = 'Hello world!';
let pattern = /(<!-- js starts -->)[^!]+(<!-- js ends -->)/gim;

gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(replaceString(pattern,function(n0,n1,n2){
        return n1 + '\n' + replacement + '\n' + n2;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('output'));
```

Result of `output/index.html`:

```html
<!-- js starts -->
Hello world!
<!-- js ends -->
```

By the way, you said you were trying to use Regex, but it looks like you were passing in a string literal, not a Regex literal (what I use above), or the result of calling the RegExp constructor, like `var pattern = new RegExp('hello\s{0,1}World');`

---

Although I won't give advice on what you should and shouldn't use, I will point out that `gulp-string-replace` has not been updated for a while, and has [an open issue](https://github.com/tomaszczechowski/gulp-string-replace/issues/16) that actually affected my answer; I tried to use inline back-references (e.g. `$1\nHello World\n$2`) and it did not work, forcing me to use the callback function argument. `gulp-string-replace` just uses [replacestream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replacestream) for the actual replacement  operation.